# Jira connection timeout errors

Tags: jira

I just installed Jira on an EC2 instance using puppet. While I was able to get everything installed and running, I'm seeing performance issues when logging into the application. Once I'm in, everything seems to work fine, but it takes forever to login.

Below are my specs.

- Puppet Module: puppet-jira
- OS: CentOS 7
- Java Version: Oracle JDK 1.8.0_60
- Jira version: 7.1.9

I've pulled the following stack trace out of catalina.out. Seems to be an issue with Jira gadgets, but not sure. How can I fix this error? Please note I masked my IP to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080:

```
2016-07-07 13:06:49,013 http-nio-8080-exec-10 ERROR tester 780x980x1 vn0otp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /secure/Dashboard.jspa [c.a.g.r.internal.http.HttpClientFetcher] Unable to retrieve response
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 [/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] failed: Connection timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.renderer.internal.http.HttpClientFetcher.fetch(HttpClientFetcher.java:85)
    at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.DefaultMessageBundleFactory.fetchBundle(DefaultMessageBundleFactory.java:138)
    at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.DefaultMessageBundleFactory.getNestedBundle(DefaultMessageBundleFactory.java:111)
    at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.DefaultMessageBundleFactory.getBundle(DefaultMessageBundleFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.variables.VariableSubstituter.substitute(VariableSubstituter.java:47)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.renderer.internal.GadgetSpecFactoryImpl.getGadgetSpec(GadgetSpecFactoryImpl.java:127)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.renderer.internal.GadgetSpecFactoryImpl.getGadgetSpec(GadgetSpecFactoryImpl.java:79)
    ... 2 filtered
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4005.getGadgetSpec(Unknown Source)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.GadgetFactoryImpl.createSpecificationBasedGadget(GadgetFactoryImpl.java:118)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.GadgetFactoryImpl.access$000(GadgetFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.GadgetFactoryImpl$1.visit(GadgetFactoryImpl.java:72)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.GadgetFactoryImpl$1.visit(GadgetFactoryImpl.java:69)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.GadgetState.accept(GadgetState.java:132)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.GadgetFactoryImpl.createDashboardItem(GadgetFactoryImpl.java:69)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.StateConverterImpl.convertStateToGadget(StateConverterImpl.java:28)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl$DashboardItemStateConverter.apply(DashboardImpl.java:196)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl$DashboardItemStateConverter.apply(DashboardImpl.java:194)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:799)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:651)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:650)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.hasNext(TransformedIterator.java:43)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:547)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:272)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:226)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.rest.representations.RepresentationFactoryImpl.createDashboardRepresentation(RepresentationFactoryImpl.java:48)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.velocity.DashboardEmbedder.dashboardToJsonObject(DashboardEmbedder.java:47)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.velocity.DashboardView.getLayoutsJson(DashboardView.java:164)
    at com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.velocity.DashboardView.writeTo(DashboardView.java:77)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.action.Dashboard$1.render(Dashboard.java:231)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.tags.RenderTag.doStartTag(RenderTag.java:37)
    at jsp.secure.views.dashboard_jsp._jspx_meth_ww_005frender_005f0(dashboard_jsp.java:118)
    at jsp.secure.views.dashboard_jsp._jspService(dashboard_jsp.java:73)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    ... 29 filtered
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    ... 50 filtered
    at com.atlassian.greenhopper.jira.filters.ClassicBoardRouter.doFilter(ClassicBoardRouter.java:59)
    ... 74 filtered
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.doFilter(JiraSecurityFilter.java:70)
    ... 89 filtered
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 318 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the gadgets (or some other code) try to pull some info through rest and they fail due to wrong base url. Set the base URL so it's resolved externally and locally. By locally I mean that you should be able to wget https://your-jira-domain.com from ssh session.
The url is set in the System Settings screen:
[image]